# Get smaller log messages on cypress

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, material-ui, cypress

I want to convert the cypress messages to a smaller string, for example:

Cypress log

[image: Cypress log]

Be converted to:

`-assert expected #buy-price-field to have value 17,169.00`.

How can I do it?

I read the document but I can't find somethings that can solve my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of short form `cy.get('input').should('have.value', '17,169.00')` use callback form.

Something like

```js
cy.get('input')
  .should($el => {
    const price = "17,169.00";
    const message = `expected #buy-price-field to have value ${price}`;
    expect($el.val(), message).to.eq(price);
  })
```